# How can I make a form render when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm newbie in javascript and I want to render a form when user clicks a button, I tried different methods but I wasn't successful. Here is the code:

```
 <a href="" id="reply">Reply</a>
 <form action="" method="post" >
     <textarea name="comment" class="comment_textarea"></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5"> 
     <input type="submit" class="btn"  value="Reply">
 </form>
```

I'm using this in threaded comments. I just want to render this form when user clicks reply button and otherwise this form should not be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @des said, you could use `a#reply` as a trigger. In jquery it only needs a couple of lines of code:

```
  $('.reply').click(function() { 

  $(this).parent().find('.reply-form').toggle(); 


 });​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hLHJ3/3/)

Comment: This will work, but beware, it will toggle **all** forms on your website (visible forms will be hidden and hidden will be shown).

Comment: @des and menislici,  I have threaded comments in the site, Have a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/hLHJ3/2. I'm able to toggle form by pressing reply in the first comment but other reply buttons are not working, I have long threads like this, Do you have any ideas, how to fix it?

Comment: @user1509863 [improved example] (http://jsfiddle.net/hLHJ3/3/). Note: I have made a few changes to the html (changed `reply-form` and `reply` id-s to classes, as @des has explained as well)

Answer (score 3):

You can hide form using css:

```
 <a hred="" id="reply">Reply</a>
 <form action="" method="post" id="reply-form" style="display:none">
     <textarea name="comment" class="comment_textarea"></textarea>
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="5"> 
     <input type="submit" class="btn"  value="Reply">
 </form>
```

and then show it when user clicks reply button:

```
$('#reply').click(function() { $('#reply-form').toggle(); });
```

**UPDATE** Now as I saw your HTML:

Firstly, never use one id for more than one element, use class instead:

```
<a hred="" class="reply">Reply</a>
```

Now you can use `next()` to toggle form:

```
//  for each element with class reply, find next form element and toggle visibility
$('.reply').click(function() { $(this).next('form').toggle(); });​​​​
```